# pdfLatex warning : PDF inclusion : invalid other resource which is no dict : ignored

Tags: pdftex, pdf, warnings

i am receiving this problem when attempting to add an existing PDF into a latex document

```
pdfTeX warning: /usr/texbin/pdflatex (file ./filename.pdf): PDF inclusion
: invalid other resource which is no dict (key 'ProcSets', type <array>); ignored.
```

Any help on this, happening on 2 different file i am trying to include in the PDF output

Comment: Post the code that you use to add this document to the existing one.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 5):

PDF spec says, that all entries (resource types) in `Resources` dictionary must be (sub-)dictionaries themselves, *except* `Procset` entry, which is array. On the other hand, unknown entries in any dictionary are ignored.

In your file, there's `ProcSets` (see the difference?) entry. It's not dictionary, hence the warning. It's unknown key, therefore ignored. You can safely ignore it, too. Anyway, `ProcSet` entry is optional and obsolete since 1.4 -- i.e. for more than 10 years. It's interesting, still, what application creates such files?

Comment: I believe it might be ICopy as I have the same problem.

Comment: I got this error with Chrome using Print to pdf.

Comment: I got this from a pdf exported by app.diagrams.net

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the other answer, `ProcSet` is obsolete in PDF, and `ProcSets` is a mis-spelling anyway: it will be ignored by compliant readers.  I suspect PDF files containing the `ProcSets` resource are created with Skia/PDF -- code here:

https://github.com/google/skia/blob/master/src/pdf/SkPDFResourceDict.cpp.

This is the case with PDF files exported from Draw.IO, anyway. Update: that bug in the Skia/PDF library has now been corrected, but it will take time for the fix to be incorporated in applications.

In summary, you can ignore the message: pdfTeX will not copy the offending resource into its output, but that does no damage.  I have modified my own installation of pdfTeX to correct `ProcSets` to `ProcSet` in order to quieten the warning.

Here's the patch I used, before recompiling pdftex and related programs.

```
diff --git a/src/tex/pdflib/pdftoepdf.cc b/src/tex/pdflib/pdftoepdf.cc
--- a/src/tex/pdflib/pdftoepdf.cc
+++ b/src/tex/pdflib/pdftoepdf.cc
@@ -1014,7 +1014,8 @@
             key = obj1->dictGetKey(i);
             if (strcmp("Font", key) == 0)
                 copyFontResources(&obj2);
-            else if (strcmp("ProcSet", key) == 0)
+            else if (strcmp("ProcSet", key) == 0
+                     || strcmp("ProcSets", key) == 0)
                 copyProcSet(&obj2);
             else
                 copyOtherResources(&obj2, key);
```

You will have to find the appropriate source file yourself within the directory structure of your TeX distribution.

Comment: Is there a way to silence this warning?

Comment: I've added to the answer the patch I used -- but you will have to build pdftex and related programs from source.