# How to correct the warning message: PDF inclusion: invalid other resource which is no dict?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, warnings

I'd like to solve the warning message cited in title. My document class is `\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3} % onecolumn (second format)`. I tried to use, but there is not a answer. [pdfLatex warning : PDF inclusion : invalid other resource which is no dict : ignored](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154919/pdflatex-warning-pdf-inclusion-invalid-other-resource-which-is-no-dict-ign)

Comment: Post an MWE! How do you include the other PDF? Does it work using another file (=another PDF)?

Comment: The question you cited has an answer explaining the problem. So?